# How do I init/update a git submodule in a working tree after pushing to a bare working directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository with an attached working tree that I'm pushing to a bare repo on a remote.
The repository includes a submodule.

**At the remote end**: I check out the repo to a working tree `git checkout -f` having set `GIT-DIR` and `GIT-WORK-TREE` env vars.

In the working tree I now see all the expected files and an empty directory for the submodule ('MySubmodule').

I then do:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

This errors with a message like:

```
working tree '../../workTree/' already exists
Clone of 'git@github.com:user/MySubmodule.git' into submodule path 'MySubmodule' failed
```

The empty submodule directory has now also 'vanished' from the working tree...

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this, basically I just want to check out the submodule files as I would with 'git submodule update'.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? If so I'd be happy to know how

Comment: a bare repo isn't supposed to have a working tree and therefore should not have a working tree for a submodule. [similar info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/push-to-non-bare-repository#comment29366144_1764380)

Comment: I had the same problem when writing a deploy script, it seems that there is no way for initializing submodules in a checked out bare repository.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when your running "git submodule update" you can't set the GIT_WORK_TREE... it will try to use this as the working tree for the submodule, not for the super project.

I've had to update my servers post-update script...

```
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir="$PROJECT_DIR" --work-tree="$PROJECT_DEMO" checkout -f;

cd "$PROJECT_DEMO";
/usr/local/bin/git --git-dir="$PROJECT_DIR" submodule update --init --recursive;
```

Notice I didn't set env variables, and that the submodule command did not have the "--work-tree" set... it seems that it needs to work from the cwd.

Comment: This didn't work.
remote: fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat would you be able to post a full answer?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat never mind, I got it thanks to your short comment.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Craign This saved me a lot of time.
  
`GIT_DIR=/var/www/src/mysite.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git submodule update --init --recursive` was giving me 

`fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.` error 

while  `git --git-dir=/var/www/src/mysite.git/ --work-tree=/var/www/html/ submodule update --init --recursive` worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need to checkout a bare repo? Just clone it somewhere else and work with a normal, non-bare repo.

But if you really need to do it, you can rename the folder to `.git`, change `bare = true` to `bare = false` in `.git/config` and then do `git checkout`.

Comment: I use a bare repo for the reasons described here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html

All of the bare repo functionality works fine apart from checking out the submodule to the detached working tree.